# UTC time readed from a json time change to UTC+1 in the same command

Tags: json, curl, jq

I do a curl with this command :

curl "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=46.745995&lng=7.122781&date=today" | jq '.results.sunrise'

the result is :

"5:31:51 AM"

I am living in UTC+1 and I need to add one hour in the same command.

If the command don't work you need to install jq with apt install jq or download it for Windows

Comment: I need that the result of the command will be : "6:31:51 AM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use this invocation of jq:

```
jq '.results.sunrise
| strptime("%I:%M:%S %p")
| {h: ((.[3] + 1) % 24), m:.[4], s:.[5]}
| if .h < 12 then "\(.h):\(.m):\(.s) AM"
  elif .h == 12 then "\(.h):\(.m):\(.s) PM"
  else "\(.h - 12):\(.m):\(.s) PM"
  end '
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for